# Nagios core check: Is it possible to pipe sort -u in a check command?

Tags: nagios

Is it possible to **`|sort -u`** in a check command?

```
#check_active_Node
define command{
    command_name    check_active_node_list
    command_line    /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_active_node.sh '$ARG1$' '$ARG2$'|sort -u
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally no.  The pipe character "|" would normally not be allowed as part of the line being executed by Nagios - there are important security reasons for this.  There are ways around it, but I'd not recommend using any of them.  Your best solution would be to modify the plugin (create a check_active_node_custom.sh and edit that), and add what ever sorting you need to the script itself.  Remember that the Nagios system expects certain return codes and text from a plugin, and that should still function as expected after your edits.